# Hiding a block element without using display:none with a modified container with 0 height and width?

Tags: html, css

https://codepen.io/sayaman/pen/gOmRepQ

Hiding a block element without using display:none?

Ok, so I learned you can't hide a parent div without also hiding the children, although in this case I can also hide the + button we see in the above codepen because it's a child of the parent, I would avoid using hide in the situation where there are many components to hide. Is there a way to hide everything without adding the display:hide styling in every remaining elements that aren't hidden by setting the height and width to 0?

```
<div class="multiselect" id="countries" multiple="multiple" data-target="multi-0">
    <div class="title noselect">
        <span class="text">Select</span>
        <span class="close-icon">&times;</span>
        <span class="expand-icon">&plus;</span>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <option value="us">USA</option>
        <option value="fr">France</option>
        <option value="gr">Greece</option>
        <option value="uk">United Kingdom</option>
        <option value="ge">Germany</option>
        <option value="sp">Spain</option>
        <option value="it">Italy</option>
        <option value="ch">China</option>
        <option value="jp">Japan</option>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="lol" type="button">Click Me</div> 
<div style="margin-top: 10px;">
    You can select multiple values from the dropdown and delete all of them at the same time, by clicking on the 'x' button.
</div>
```

The above is the html.

```
#countries {height: 0px; width:0px;}
.title>span, .title, .expand-icon {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
}
```

This is the styling I added to get rid of the former dropdown span. I did this to replace it with a div of my choosing so I can prevent the dropdown span of changing appearance like they do in most dropdown plugins. If you have any creative solutions, share them.

Comment: You can hide it using `opacity: 0;`, but I'm not sure that's what you're looking for...

Comment: Wait, you can hide anything with opacity: 0; and not only text?

Comment: You can afaik...